# Datatable Fixed Column (Right Only) Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using JQuery Datatable and I ran into a problem when I used fixed column.
[It has been showing two times my fixed column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlSCh.png)

I'm using serverside processing and that's my code:

```
dataTable = table.dataTable({
            fixedColumns:   {
                leftColumns: 0,
                rightColumns: 1
            },
            scrollX:true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            "fnDrawCallback":function(oSettings) {
                $('div.choosePage select').val(dataTable.DataTable().page());
            },
            "pagingType":"bootstrap_full_number",
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
             "data":GETDATA,
             "dataSrc":SETAJAXDATA
            },
            "fnInitComplete":completeProcess,
            "colReorder": true,
            "order": [
            [0, 'asc']
            ],
            "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-4 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-5 col-sm-12 toolbar'p><'col-md-push-1 col-md-3 col-sm-12 toolbar choosePage'>>", // horizobtal scrollable datatable
        })
```

Ajax is working good and there is no problem when I used fixed column on left side,but when I used it on right side i'm running into this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in Jquery Datatable if you haven't setup scrollY from the options, make sure you set some value.

Because when you inspect the element you can see scroll-y overflow is auto. If you set it as hidden or not setup a value from the options, there you go, you see the space at the right side.

Incase you do not want to use scroll-y at all, then you need to make your hands dirty with some css code by giving some minor margin which is an ugly solution. But I cannot see any other option for you.

It's a shame for Jquery datatable plugin.

Below shows an example option list from the plugin website.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 0,
            rightColumns: 1
        }
    } );
} );
```